# QR code сканер на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, qr

Вопрос состоит в следующем, есть ли готовые решения для следующей задачи, 
На сайте есть база данных в которой храниться информация по клиентам одна из ячеек хранит уникальный код который ранее был сконвертирован в QR код для каждого клиента, далее у клиентов приходящих к месту регистрации есть с собой распечатанный листок с QR-кодом, нужно считать с листка QR-код -> отправить запрос в базу данных сайта и извлечить соответствующую запись либо вывести сообщение что такой записи по этому коду не найдено. Я так полагаю что здесь нужен ручной штрих код сканер - в этом случае возникает вопрос есть ли готовый софт чтобы он выполнял нужные действия описанные выше ил или нужно нанимать чтобы допиливали под нужды?!

Comment: Хм... Веб-камера? :)

Comment: Ок, можно веб камеру,  меня больше интересует вопрос вытащить считанную информацию из бд автоматом

Answer (score 1):

Кодируй в QR ссылку с нужным уникальным кодом. Например https://bilet.local?check.php?code=165441651afdsfgfgdf
Доступ к странице закрывается из вне. На смартфоне заводится vpn (через который возможен доступ к той странице) и считыватель QR (c автоматическим переходом по ссылке). Готово.